# jQuery selector to count number of empty text-boxes doesn't work in IE9 / IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a form with many text-boxes for user input, all of which have `placeholder` attributes set on them. It is required that the user fills out all of the text inputs which have a certain pattern of `name` attribute value. On form submit, we are using a a jQuery selector to find/count all of the empty inputs (those which have an empty `value` attribute) so that we can highlight these `input` elements for the user to fill out. Unfortunately, I have found that Internet Explorer 8 & 9 (and probably earlier) consider `placeholder` values to be a `value`.

#### HTML:

```
<input name="tb1" type="text" placeholder="foo" />
<input name="tb2" type="text" placeholder="bar" />
<input name="tb3" type="text" placeholder="baz" />
<button id="b1" type="button">Count Empty Text-boxes</button>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$('#b1').click(function () {
    var emptyTextboxes = $('input[name^="tb"][value=""]:visible');
    alert('Num empty text-boxes: ' + emptyTextboxes.length);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/r6jC7/1/

In Firefox, Chrome, & IE10+ the JS will only count the text-boxes which have had text typed into them, regardless of their `placeholder` values. In IE9 and below, you will always see the message "Num empty text-boxes: 0", because the browser seems to be counting the placeholders.

### My Question:

Is there a way I can update/change my jQuery selector in a way which IE8 and IE9 will behave similarly to modern browsers?

**jQuery version:** 1.7.2

Comment: It seems JSFiddle doesn't work in IE11's Document Mode for IE8. If you want to try out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6jC7/1/), either just create your own HTML file to experiment with or [install an IE VM](http://www.modern.ie/en-us).

Comment: ... or use [BrowserStack](http://browserstack.com).

Comment: when you do your loop you could get attr('placeholder') and compare it to the value and if it is the same do the same you would do for a blank

Comment: Are you sure it’s not just expecting `:not([value])`? You’ve not specified the `value` attributes, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is direct selector which will be able to accomplish this. However, using jQuery's filtering functionality should provide the desired result set.

```
$('#b1').click(function () {
    var emptyTextboxes = $('input[name^="tb"]:visible');

    emptyTextboxes = emptyTextboxes.filter(function(index, el){ 
        return el.value == '' || el.value == el.getAttribute('placeholder');
    });

    alert('Num empty text-boxes: ' + emptyTextboxes.length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `value` attribute is one inconsistency between jQuery and what really happens in the browser. You’re exposing it because `:visible` forces the selector into “jQuery mode”.

You can select based on what’s *really* in the HTML (`:not([value])`) and filter afterwards, relying on jQuery’s optimization:

```
var emptyTextboxes = $('input[name^="tb"]:not([value])').filter(':visible');
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/r6jC7/1/) That feels a bit fragile, though. How about:

```
var emptyTextboxes = $('input[name^=tb]').filter(':visible').filter(function() {
    return !this.value;
});
```

That’ll work for both `<input>` and `<input value="">`.